# jQuery keyup checking password is very slow

Tags: jquery

I was hoping someone could help me with the following. I have a password input box that the user inputs their password and it automatically checks their password with the database using the following code

```
 $('input[name=currentpassword]').keyup(function(){
                var currentcheck = $(this).val();
                var dataString='thisConfirm='+ currentcheck +'&userid='+$('input[name=userid]').val();
                PasswordChecking=   $.ajax({
                                        type:"POST",
                                        url:"/assets/inc/password-check.php",
                                        data:dataString,
                                        dataType:'html',
                                        context:document.body,
                                        global:false,
                                        async:false,
                                        success:function(data){
                                            return data}
                                            }).responseText;
                    checkconfirms(emailconfirm, passconfirm, PasswordChecking);
        });
```

But what I'm noticing is there’s a delay between each key up and was hoping there was  a way or alternative to check the inputted password as each key stroke is delayed or doesn’t recognize it until the Ajax returns

Comment: Using ajax on `keyup` is not a good idea. Instead use `onblur` or `blur`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a timeout that cancels the ajax request so as to not check the password on every keyup if the user is typing fast, but only when the user has finished typing. Also you should be using asynchronous calls to avoid locking the browser, something like this :

```
$('input[name=currentpassword]').on('keyup', function() {
    var data = {thisConfirm : this.value, userid: $('input[name=userid]').val()};

    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));

    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/assets/inc/password-check.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',
            context: document.body,
            global: false,
        }).done(function() {
            checkconfirms(emailconfirm, passconfirm, PasswordChecking);
        })
    },400);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `blur` or `focusout` events, as Adil suggested, is one option. An alternative is to use `setTimeout()` to delay checking the password, so that you aren't sending an AJAX request on every keystroke. Instead you'd send a single AJAX request X seconds after they stopped typing in that input.

```
var checkPassword;
$('input[name=currentpassword]').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(checkPassword);
    checkPassword = setTimeout(function() {verifyPassword(this)}, 1000); // this would delay calling verifyPassword() by 1 second
});

function verifyPassword(element) {
    var currentcheck = element.value;
    // do your AJAX call here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `async:false,` which should be true for async call. I would suggest you to check the password on jquery event **[focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)** instead of keyup.

```
$('input[name=currentpassword]').focusout(function(){
            var currentcheck = $(this).val();
            var dataString='thisConfirm='+ currentcheck +'&userid='+$('input[name=userid]').val();
            PasswordChecking=   $.ajax({
                                        type:"POST",
                                        url:"/assets/inc/password-check.php",
                                        data:dataString,
                                        dataType:'html',
                                        context:document.body,
                                        global:false,
                                       async:true,
                                       success:function(data){
                                        //return data
                                        alert("here you would decide on data for valiadation success");
                                        }
                               }).responseText;
                checkconfirms(emailconfirm, passconfirm, PasswordChecking);
    });
```